# Cannot run old elasticsearch on m1 chip (with rosetta2)

Tags: elasticsearch, apple-m1

My current project requires me to use `elasticsearch:2.4.6-alpine` docker image. The container seems running correctly and I am able to go inside the container using CLI. But when `curl http://localhost:9200` executed it says:

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Tried the same curl command from inside the container and it says:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

The elasticsearch service seems not exists when I use `rc-status list` from inside the container. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you get any solution for your above problem? I'm facing the same one.

Comment: Alas the only real solution is to get a proper computer not a Fisher Price one. I've been on one of these Fisher Price M1s for about 6 months now and I'm finally giving up and going back to Windows. Much cheaper, much faster, much more reliable. I hate Apple computer with a passion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to rebuild the elastic search image on your M1 Mac. Just search the source code for particular version on GitHub and build the docker image.

Comment: more information on how to do that ? where are the sources located for each version ? how to build them into a docker container ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like support for M1 was only added in elasticsearch 7.12.0. Use that version or anything newer.

```yaml
image: elasticsearch:7.16.3
```

Some say it works better when pulling the image file from [elastic directly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode), not via dockerhub.

```yaml
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
```

More discussion: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/arm-docker-image/268588

### Legacy elasticsearch (v2)

```
any help here is appreciated :)
```

I am still looking for any way to run legacy elasticsearch (version 2) on a M1 mac via Rosetta. So far, no luck.

Update: elasticsearch ***V2*** doesn't work because of a known bug in Docker's qemu translation from x64 to arm. Workarounds maybe possible (at least for v6+)

> Well... the QEMU emulation is frankly not ideal and there are no guarantees there. If you need to run ES 6.x on Apple silicon the best option is probably to use a proper aarch64 JDK and use the tarball distribution. Still no guarantees here as this isn't a supported configuration. Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69767

Comment: Were you able to make any progress with getting ES v2 to work? (I'm stuck with trying to use v1.7)

Comment: No progress. On Apple Silicon, It looks like running anything before v7.12.0 will not be possible using Docker (maybe you could build from source... but maybe not).